# Can I export a render of the Solid Mode?

Tags: rendering, export

so am new to blender and just finish the animation but rather than export to rendered, I like the solid mode more. so can I export it to solid mode?

Answer (score 3):

Set up your camera view using <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. Uncheck the <kbd>Viewport Overlays</kbd> by clicking the icon arrowed top right, Then use <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Viewport Render Animation</kbd>

[image]